# Custom event listeners for wxpython widgets

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

as in the title, is it possible to add a custom event listener for wx widget and if so, how?  More particularly I am trying to add one which listens to the changes of SelStart and SelEnd attributes of wx.Slider.
Thanks!

Comment: Do any of the events listed here http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_slider.html work for your purposes?

Comment: There may be a complicated method to make it work with some of them, but I am also interested whether custom listeners are possible in general.

Comment: According to [MSDN doc regarding TrackBar Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760149(v=vs.85).aspx) (on which ``wx.Slider`` is based), the range can be changed from code but there is no interaction from the user side. It also says that if one should want to limit valid slider positions to the range, this had to be implemented by the programmer. Is it that what you want?

Comment: yep. in my application the users clicks the left mouse button to set the selection start and right mouse button to set its end. I cannot use mouse click events for certain reasons, so wanted to know if a custom listener for the changes in these values is implementable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Below is the code for custom listener for wx.slider, I am calling it inside other listener's handler.

> You can call this customize listener from the point where SelStart and SelEnd changing.

```
import wx 
import wx.lib.newevent
DialogRespondEvent, EVT_DIALOG_RESPOND_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
class Mywin(wx.Frame): 
    
    def __init__(self, parent, title): 
        super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (250,150))  
        self.InitUI() 
 
    def InitUI(self):    
        pnl = wx.Panel(self) 
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
        self.Bind(EVT_DIALOG_RESPOND_EVENT, self.testing) 
        self.sld = wx.Slider(pnl, value = 10, minValue = 1, maxValue = 100,
        style = wx.SL_HORIZONTAL|wx.SL_LABELS) 
        
        vbox.Add(self.sld,1,flag = wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL |     wx.TOP, border = 20) 
        self.sld.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.OnSliderScroll) 
        self.txt = wx.StaticText(pnl, label = 'Hello',style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)                
        vbox.Add(self.txt,1,wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL) 

        pnl.SetSizer(vbox) 
        self.Centre() 
        self.Show(True)

    def testing(self,evt):
        print "you can do whatever you want here"

   def OnSliderScroll(self, e): 
       obj = e.GetEventObject() 
       val = obj.GetValue() 
       font = self.GetFont() 
       font.SetPointSize(self.sld.GetValue()) 
       self.txt.SetFont(font)
       evt = DialogRespondEvent()
       wx.PostEvent(self, evt)

ex = wx.App() 
Mywin(None,'Slider demo') 
ex.MainLoop()
```